# How do i set up two monitors with one being set to 4k 144 hz and one being 4k 120hz

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors

I just got two Acer Nitro XV273K Pbmiipphzx 27" and I tried to set one to 4k 144hz and one to 120hz  because I only have 3 display ports on my gpu and 144hz requires 2. but when I set one to 144hz the other gets disabled and when I try to enable it in the windows display settings it just keeps getting disabled.

Any ideas on how to fix this and get this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might be running into a bandwidth issue.

Comment: that would make sense, do you know of anyway to fix that other than adding another gpu?

Comment: It is possible the cable can't handle it, or it can be the GPU that can't handle it. Calculate what bandwidth your entire resolution will be (both screens combined) and assume 60hz.  Then calculate what it would be for 120 and 144 hz (120 is already double) and see if your GPU can actually output that much and you have your answer.